# Rotate hi nibble and lo nibble individually in x86

Tags: x86, byte

I'm having trouble finding a way to rotate the individual nibbles of a byte in assembly x86. For example, I want to rotate the hi nibble left 1, and the lo nibble right 1, so that 0xB4 becomes 0x72.

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes known as "bit group moving", which you can implement in assembly:

```
x = ((x & 0x70) << 1)
  | ((x & 0x01) << 3)
  | ((x & 0x80) >> 3)
  | ((x & 0x0e) >> 1);
```

It's basically a brute force way to implement permutations, moving every "group" of bits that has the same shift count/direction at the same time. It tends to be a bit verbose.

An interesting strategy for 8-bit permutations is "permute by multiply", which unfortunately involves some huge constants:

```
mov rdx, 0x0101010101010101
imul rax, rdx ; replicate byte x8 (only 4 are needed but spaced out)
mov rdx, 0x700080000E000100
and rax, rdx  ; isolate the 4 different parts
mov rdx, 0x0008000080002002
imul rax, rdx ; shift/combine parts
shr rax, 56
```

This has a significantly larger code size, unless the huge constants are loaded through memory operands.

But all this is really doing is avoiding a 256 byte lookup table, which is much simpler and in many cases faster (except when the table is cold) and only slightly bigger.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no assembly instruction that will help with this; you just have to explicitly put the bits where you want them.

```
x = (x >> 3 & 0x10) | (x << 1 & 0xe0) | (x << 3 & 0x08) | (x >> 1 & 0x07);
```